# How to handle 'Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect' in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keystore

While trying to sign a new version of a published App via Visual Studio (V16.6.2) i got the error

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

which was a huge surprise for me since i was quite sure of my password.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of trying different variations of the password i gave a try to a [password-recover tool](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki) (suggested in [a post in **Medium**](https://medium.com/reversebits/how-to-recover-data-of-your-android-keystore-8adb07d2b660)) just to find out that the password i was sure about was actually the right one. Yet, the password kept being rejected by **Visual Studio**, so i did some research and i came to [a thread in **github**](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4036) where the main post states

> Password have the next symbols: @ ^ ] $

then i thought, "*ok, my password also has a special symbol: '%'*", so, after being sure my password was correct, i opened the **adb Command Prompt** in **Visual Studio**

[image]

and used **keytool** command to change both **Key Password** and **Keystore Password** (those passwords are the same for **keystore**s created in old **Visual Studio** versions!):

```
keytool.exe -keypasswd -alias myalias -keystore "pathtokeystore"
keytool.exe -storepasswd -alias myalias -keystore "pathtokeystore"
```

By doing so, i changed both passwords (same character combination for both again, so i only have to remember one!), but now without special characters.

Voilà! Now i could sign my app...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i had a "\" symbol in my password. Escaping it like so - "\\" did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I get that problem and It's really annoying the lack of information of what happening.
I solved with following steps:

1. creating the APK archive in Visul Studio;
2. Sign the APK with an amazing tool called uber-apk-signer (https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer)

Comment: ok, so my last comment on this issue was deleted by @chrisf, here I go again.  I've tried this solution in VSMac.  It does not work for me.  VSMac is a different product, so I am wondering what I should do different to solve this problem.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What's happened?

Comment: polotto - I'm using VS for Mac. I've got the latest stable version. I have tried this solution. I am using the imported certificate, so I think I have modified the correct certificate. I am still getting the errror "Keystore was tampered with or password is incorrect".  I have my settings in VSMac set for the certificate. I have run androidbruteforce_v1.05.jar with a wordlist and verified my cert password is what I think it is. Unfortunately, VSMac is still giving me the same error message. Any ideas on this for things I should look at?

Comment: I assume that there is something I am missing on this when using VSMac, but danged if I can figure out what it is.

Comment: But my solution is about using another tool to do this job. Did you try my solution?

Comment: No, i have not.  I am trying to keep all of my solutions within the standard set of tools that come from the Android SDK, so that is no knock on your solution.

Comment: @WallaceB.McClure did u manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @ÂngeloPolotto Apologies for not answering on this previously. I walked through and signed the file manually using the android tools.

Comment: @Mr.Onion  I walked through the manually signing document from microsoft.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk