# Visual Studio Mac - signing failed: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Weird problem.  I am trying to compile and deploy a Xamarin forms app to the google appstore for android.  I keep getting a "signing failed: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" message when I put the password in for my key.  I thought I had forgotten my password or had messed up the file.  No, that's not it.  I know this because I used this brute force utility, and it said my password that I fed it immediately.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki

I think I am typing in my password correct, though with these fat fingers you never know.  I've tried it so many time, so I don't think that my typing is the problem.

Is there anything else that could be causing this problem?  I figure that this is something on my end between the chair and the keyboard, but I just can't figure this out.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: There is a similar thread, you can first check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570364/how-to-handle-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect-in-visual-s .

Comment: I am back on this problem.  I am using VSMac.  the solution as described in the link does not work for me on my Mac.  I think I am making the change in the correct directory for the VSMac.  I am using the directory as described by my preferences setting in VSMac.  Any other ideas on this?  TIA.  @JessieZhang-MSFT