# Xamarin Forms - Android apk signing - Signing Packages Failed, keystore was tampered with

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022, android-keystore, android-app-signing

VS2022
I have succesfully built and archived my Xamarin.Forms app. I've used ad hoc distribution many times in this project, successfully.
With my last archive, it failed to sign the package, quoting the error Signing Packages Failed. 'Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.'

I used this process after successfully archiving:
I click Distribute => Ad Hoc.
I select my signing Identity, and select a save location.
I am prompted for my password, which contains only 6 lower case letters.
I get an error:
Signing Packages Failed.
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Following other SO threads I have:

I've rebooted.
I've rebuilt and re-archived.
I have since deleted the keystore.
I've reinstalled xamarin forms after deleting the 'mono for android' folder.
Still, even with a brand new key (taking care for no special characters), the package signing fails.

I'm absolutely tearing my hair out - can anyone advise how to fix this ridiculous problem?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570364/how-to-handle-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect-in-visual-s

Comment: I found a comment on the GitHub [the Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4036). You can refer to this

Comment: Thank you Rafael and Guangyu - those threads bother cover the special characters in password issues.  My password has no special characters.

Comment: This is a issue that it can not be reproduced easily. But I noticed many people who met the problem solved the problem by changing both alias password and keystore password. If you can not fix the issue you can report the issue.